# .htaccess Url Redirect Issues

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have two folders on my domain that i have renamed. I wanted to add some redirection scripts into my .htaccess file so that users with the old links get to the right location. I tried using using;

```
RedirectMatch 301 /oldfolder/subsection-01/(.*) example.com/new-folder/subsection/$1

RedirectMatch 301 /oldfolder/(.*) example.com/new-folder/$1
```

and they both worked! However all my image links broke, because their file paths on the server have the following path:

```
example.com/sites/default/files/**oldfolder**/filename.jpg
```

I Have been looking for a way to either exclude references to .jpg files or ensure that only the folders with that include the domain uri e.g. 'example.com/oldfolder' are acted upon but to no avail.

I tried the following techniques;

```
RedirectMatch 301 %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com/oldfolder/subsection-01/(.*)    example.com/new-folder/subsection/$1

RedirectMatch 301  example.com/oldfolder/(.*)  example.com/new-folder/$1

RewriteRule %{HTTP_HOST}.example\.com/oldfolder/subsection-01/$ example.com/new-folder/subsection/$1 [L]

RewriteRule %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com/oldfolder/(.*) example.com/new-folder/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But they've either resulted in server 501 errors or done nothing at all.

I Would appreciate any useful assistance the community can provide.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use start anchor in your regex to make sure your your pattern is matched only when it is at start:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/oldfolder/subsection-01/(.*) http://example.com/new-folder/subsection/$1

RedirectMatch 301 ^/oldfolder/(.*) http://example.com/new-folder/$1
```